# Как сделать, чтобы и при совпадении и username и email выдавало ошибку, что такой пользователь уже существует? Выдает только при совпадении username

Tags: php, sql, json, api

case 'register':

```
if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('username','email', 'password', 'phone'))){
  
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$gender = $_POST['phone']; 

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?");
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute([$username, $password]);

if($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$response['error'] = true;
$response['message'] = 'Пользователь уже зарегистрирован';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменить `OR` на `AND` скорее всего надо

Comment: Заменил на AND и перестало при совпадении username выдавать

Comment: Еще пароль не надо передавать вторым параметром в execute)))))

Comment: @Alexsofting  ну правильно... надо же два совпадения одновременно ....а вместо пароля надо email  передавать

Comment: Спасибо! получилось))